# Indoctrinating female agents

Tags: worldbuilding-resources, mind-control

I'm trying to make a story about **illegal** government program of luring expendable girls and indoctrinating them into becoming  deep cover agents.

The program uses the same process as the pimps and human traffickers for where they identify teens from broken families, orphans, runaways, and so on. But instead of prostitutes they create spies and assassins.

I need resources to plausibly explain the indoctrination process. The closest thing I've found so far is usually cult or cult-like related, like the Patty Hearst case.

Comment: It's called the army. It works with women the same way it works with men. Put them in a collective organization, where they are in constant contact with their comrades. Make them follow a fixed daily routine. Make them do various type exercises to exhaustion. Repeat until they feel this is normal life. Then start training for specialized roles. Repeat until they can do their tasks while three-quarters asleep. Reinforce the training between missions. On the other hand, are you _sure_ that the idea of mass-producing assassins is not ridiculous? If you have so many enemies to kill use the army.

Comment: This sounds like La Femme Nikita.

Comment: Sounds like a very expensive program. For what benefit?

Comment: You might be interested in Wikipedia's [human intelligence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_intelligence_(intelligence_gathering)) and [clandestine HUMINT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clandestine_HUMINT) pages, which cover issues around this topic in great detail.  As user535733 says, it often turns out cheaper to buy the information from your target than train a thief to steal it.

Comment: Sounds good for storytelling purposes but in reality its impractical. Trade secrets of a company my pal used to work were stolen by an intern and leaked. It turned out security protocols were so restricting that employees had to use illegal methods and risk  firing/lawsuits to get anything done. It backfired badly.

Comment: Why is it illegal? It just sounds like the government is offering employment opportunities to disadvantaged teens. Or is the illegal bit the fact it is some sort of deniable black ops?  Meanwhile... I think to create an effective spy, they have to be flexible in outlook and behaviour, not indoctrinated. For instance, someone who goes about spouting the Communist Manifesto and being outraged at capitalist lifestyles would be a rubbish cold war spy. They have to seamlessly fit in with the folks they are spying on.

Comment: @DrBob Are you joking you can recruit children like that. There is very narrow fields of jobs that minors could do in any normal country and only if it doesn't interrupt with their education. Being sent to Iran, Russia & North Korea is definitely not one of them. This reminds of https://vigilantcitizen.com/ Beta kitten articles.

Comment: @Saren. I read 'teens' to include 16 to 19 year olds. This includes people who have left school at 16 and people who are legally adult, i.e. not children. The OP says 'girls' (which is a term used for both girl children and adult women) and 'teens' (13 to 19). It doesn't specify under 16s. I must admit that I self-censored the image of a 13 year old being used as a spy, probably because I can't imagine a situation where you'd send a 13 year old to infiltrate somewhere worth spying on, instead of sending an adult! :-)

Comment: @Saren. I'm now having the mental image of a 13 year old spy and a bartender. :-)  Spy: Martini, shaken not stirred. Bartender: ID! No way are you old enough to drink!  Spy: Dammit, why didn't they cover this in my training?

Answer (score 3):

Look into how the army does it. They break you down and build you up. Another way would be the treatment of addicts. That's all about breaking behavioral patterns that are harmful.

Check the references on the following articles on:

- [Behavior modification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior_modification)
- [Indoctrination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indoctrination)
- [Abusive relationships](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_and_control_in_abusive_relationships)
- [Classical conditioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_conditioning)

Comment: Although you use several links I would argue the answers here lie largely within the links, perhaps you could summarise the important bits in your post, just in case those links go down.

Comment: He wanted resources to read up on. I just tried and show him the way. I'm not that familiar with the subject I'm confortable to give anyone a summary.

Answer (score 2):

You can take as reference the Fidai in the [Nizari sect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nizari) :

> The followers of the young Imam Hadi who joined the military were trained as the Fidai. The Fidai's bravery and self-sacrificing spirituality was due to their belief that the Nizari Imam-ul-waqt ("Imam of the time") had the Noor (light) of God within him. As such it became a religious duty for the Fidai to obey every dictate of their Imam-ul-waqt and to protect him and their community of believers without compromise even to the extent of dying for their cause.

and

> The Fidai were feared as the Assassins, but in fact did not assassinate for payment. Although they were trained in the art of spying and combat, they also practiced their Islamic mysticism at the highest level. This religious ardor turned them into formidable foes which reached an incredible level as told in the anecdote of Count Henry of Champagne. Returning from Armenia, Henry spoke with Grand Master Rashid ad-Din Sinan (known to the West as "The Old Man of the Mountain") at one of his castles, al-Kahf, in Syria. Henry pointed out that since his army was bigger by far than Sinan's, Sinan should pay him an annual tribute. 
>   Sinan refused asserting that his army was far stronger in spirit and unquestioning obedience if not in numbers. He invited Henry to witness this obedience and sacrificial spirit of his Fidai. Sinan signalled to a Fidai standing on the parapet of a high wall of his castle, to jump. The Fidai called out "God is Great" and unhesitatingly took a headlong death dive into the rocks far below.
>   The bewildered Henry asked Sinan the cause for the suicidal jump. Sinan pointed once again to the Fidai who had taken the place of the now dead Fidai. Again Sinan gave a signal to the Fidai to jump and the second Fidai also called out "God is Great" and jumped to his death. Henry was visibly shaken by the experience of witnessing the two Fidais' total disregard for their own lives. He accepted Sinan's terms of peace on a non-tribute paying basis. The Nizaris thus averted debilitating wars against them because of their Fidais' feats of self-sacrifice and assassinations of powerful enemy leaders to demonstrate the will and commitment of the community to live free from being a vassal to any Levantine power.

By the way, agencies like KGB and STASI in the past used trained women to carry on espionage, by using them as sexual weapons. They used their allure to gain the confidence of the targets, and once in their bed keeping all the informations that were needed. They were trained to even moan in the local language to keep cover. So you can easily replace the motivation from "faith in god" to "faith in a political apparatus".